# $O(n)$ algorithm to determine a number that appears more than $n/2$ times in an array of size $n$

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity

I am trying to determine $O(n)$ algorithm to determine a number that appears more than $n/2$ times in an array of size $n$, assuming that such a number does exist in the array *without resorting to an algorithm that computes the median.*

This problem came with a hint stating that

***Property 1:*** if an array of size $n$, $A := [1,...,n]$ has an element that appears more than $n/2$ times and $A[1] \neq A[2]$ then x will have the same property of appearing more than $ \frac{n-2}{2} $ in the sub-array $B:=[3,...,n] $. This property is to be used in determining the desired algorithm.

I proved this as follows:
Suppose that $x$ does not appear in the first two elements of A, then it must appear $n/2$ times in the remaining $n-2$ elements, thus $x$ will appear more than $ \frac{n-2}{2} $ times. 
Now suppose that $x=A[1]$, (the case of $x=A[2]$ being similar), then $x$ must appear more than $\frac {n}{2} - 1 = \frac {n-2}{2}$ times.  So either way Property $1$ is satisfied.

Thoughts:This technique could be used to continually shorten the number of elements in the array until there is only one element, but it works only if $A[i] \neq A[i+1]$. Here is where I am stuck. Any hints on how to proceed much appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez the question is that I am stuck and need hints on how to proceed with the requirement of the problem.

Comment: Did you think about selecting $k$ elements randomly, using it for making 4 guesses on $x$, and then travel the array counting how may times each of those guessed $x$ appear, until one appears more than $n/2$ times ?

Comment: @user1952009, that algorithm is not $O(n)$, as if your $4$ elements all happen to miss $x$, then you have not found $x$.

Comment: @vadim123 if none of the 4 elements is the correct one, you should be able to detect it soon, by detecting better guesses, and redo it. And on average, it will be better than most deterministic algorithms.

Comment: @vadim123 and on maths forum, the goal is to understand the problem. So I'm not sure you understood that the naive but efficient algorithm is probably the one I wrote (hard to implement for avoiding the worst case, but easy on the average..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hint is a special case of the following observation: Given an array $A = a_1a_2\cdots a_n$ with an element $a^*$ occurring more than $n / 2$ times, if we remove two elements $a_i$ and $a_j$ with $a_i \neq a_j$ from $A$, $a^*$ is still a majority element among the remaining elements.

Based on this observation, an algorithm with $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time and $\mathcal{O}(1)$ space exists. Below is the sketch.

> 1. $count \leftarrow 1$;
> 2. $candidate \leftarrow a_1$;
> 3. for $i \leftarrow 2$ to $n$:
> 4. $\quad$ if $count = 0$:
> 5. $\quad$ $\quad$ $candidate \leftarrow a_i$;
> 6. $\quad$ $\quad$ $count \leftarrow 1$;
> 7. $\quad$ else if $a_i \neq candidate$:
> 8. $\quad$ $\quad$ $count \leftarrow count - 1$;
> 9. $\quad$ else:
> 10. $\quad$ $\quad$ $count \leftarrow count + 1$;
> 11. return $candidate$;

The algorithm maintains after each iteration, $count$ elements (i.e., $candidate$) are unmatched. Therefore, when algorithm terminates, $candidate$ is the majority element.

Comment: This is correct. I was gonna write the same algorithm, but I would not be able to write it out nicely as above. :-)

Comment: This is a brilliant answer, but I'm afraid I'm not sure why it works, can you elaborate if possible.

Comment: @JamesDickens This algorithm is known as Moore's voting algorithm to detect majority element. Starting from left to right, we try to find pairs $(a_i, a_j)$ with $a_i \neq a_j$ on the fly. $candidate$ is an element that we have not found such pair currently among $a_1a_2\cdots a_i$ and $count$ records how many $candidate$ are unmatched. If $a_{i+1} \neq candidate$, we can match $candidate$ and $a_{i+1}$ and there are $count  - 1$ $candidate$s remaining. If $a_{i+1} = candidate$, the number of unmatched $candidate$ increment by $1$.