# Let A[1..n] be an array with n numbers. An element x in A[1..n] is said to be cool if it appears more than n/2 times

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Let A[1..n] be an array with n numbers. An element x in A[1..n] is said to be
cool if it appears more than n/2 times in A[1..n]. For instance, 5 is cool in [5, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 5], but in [1, 4, 2, 6, 5, 4, 4, 4], no element is cool.
Design a O(n) time algorithm that decides whether or not there is a cool element in A[1..n]. If there is no cool element, the algorithm must return “No”. If there is a cool element, the algorithm must return the value of the cool element. Explain why your algorithm is correct and why it does take O(n) time.
Note: You may use any algorithm that was presented in class as a black box (your
algorithm must be deterministic). Describe your algorithm in plain English.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You will get better results if (1) You make your question an actual question, not a set of instructions, which are viewed as pushy; (2) You use MathJax to format the mathematics correctly; and (3) You search for your question before posting.  This particular question was [recently](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1937816/73324) asked and answered, and in fact appears in the "related" bar on the page of this question.

Comment: Are you allowed any additional memory? Does A always contain integers? Positive integers?

Comment: From the examples I was given it seems to be only positive integers.

Comment: Have you looked at the Moore-Boyer voting algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1 : if $a$ is cool in $A[1..n]$ is it possible to have $b\neq a$ cool in $A[1..n]$?

Hint 2 : if $a$ is cool in $A[1..n]$ what can you say about the coolness of $a$ in $A[1..n/2]$ and $A[n/2..n]$?

Hint 3 : if you know that $a$ is cool in $A[1..n/2]$ and $b$ is cool in $A[n/2..n]$ how hard is it to determine if A[1..n]$ has a cool element?